# How to define multiple projects on single line (using Scala's pattern matching on assignment)?

Tags: scala, sbt

Let's say I have a helper method `defModules` that accepts some String prefix and returns a tuple/collection of modules to define, like `api`/`impl`/etc:

```
def defModules(prefix: String): (Project, Project, ...) = ???
```

or

```
def defModules(prefix: String): Seq[Project] = ???
```

It is possible to define multiple projects on single line in `build.sbt` by invoking `defModules` helper?

I tried something like

```
val (fooApi, fooImpl) = defModules("foo")
```

but got an error saying it's impossible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Back then in sbt 0.13.13 or earlier, that was possible and I personally used it a lot. It's no longer supported.

See https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/2290 and [the code responsible for the error](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/blob/1.0.x/main/src/main/scala/sbt/internal/parser/SbtParser.scala#L207).

Your best bet is to do the following:

```
val modules = defModules("foo")
val fooApi = modules._1
val fooImpl = modules._2
```

Comment: Yep, that's what I do.